# How do I pass modified string parameters?

Tags: string, rust, borrow-checker

I'm on [chapter 12 of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch12-04-testing-the-librarys-functionality.html), where a case insensitive line search is implemented. It doesn't make sense to me to implement the same logic twice, so I figured if I just called  the case sensitive search function with the parameters converted to lower case, that might work. It did not.

This is my non working code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = search("Waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");
    let b = search("waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");
    let c = search_case_insensitive("waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}

pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }

    results
}

pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase();
    let contents2: &str = &contents.to_lowercase();

    search(&query, contents2)
}
```

The error in most versions I've come up with is inevitably something very much like:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:28
   |
25 |     let contents2: &str = &contents.to_lowercase();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
28 | }
   | - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 23:1...
  --> src/main.rs:23:1
   |
23 | pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain what part of the error message you don't understand? What puzzles you about that? Thanks!

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt It's not that I don't understand the error. Apparently to_lowercase() returns a new String because a unicode string with flipped case might have a different length than the original. This new string must be deallocated at the end of the function. However the return value uses a slice of this new String, which is what is causing the error. What I don't understand is how to fix it.

Comment: Why `&'a str` for `contents2`?

Comment: @ljedrz same reason i even have a contents2, I was trying stuff more or less randomly hoping to make the error disappear. Adding the lifetime parameter was one of those. Removing it doesn't really change the error. Only changing it to 'b changes the error. But what I need to do is figure out a way to make the string outlive the function (i don't know force a borrow) or refactor so this isn't an issue anymore but I'm a bit lost

Comment: @Shepmaster I have edited the question to add minimal, complete code. You can verify that it does produce the same error. It also compiles and works as expected if you replace the return types of the functions with Vec<String> and push String::from(line) into the vector instead of just line. I guess this was sort of the solution I was looking for though perhaps there is a better way. In this example one might argue as Simon Whitehead has that the functionality is not the same and both functions should have a loop, but I was hoping for a silver bullet of sorts. Perhaps I'm too optimistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT 2:

Since you've updated the question with an MCVE and you've stated you don't care about straying away from the book examples... here is another version relying on extra allocations via the use of `String`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = search("Waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");
    let b = search("waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");
    let c = search_case_insensitive("waldo", "where in\nthe world\nis Waldo?");

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}

pub fn search<S>(query: S, contents: S) -> Vec<String> where S: Into<String> {
    let query = query.into();
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.into().lines() {
        if line.contains(&query) {
            results.push(line.into());
        }
    }

    results

}

pub fn search_case_insensitive<S>(query: S, contents: S) -> Vec<String> where S: Into<String> {
    let query = query.into().to_lowercase();
    let contents = contents.into().to_lowercase();

    search(query, contents)
}
```

Here it is [running in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=44ce6c2f9546576af29cf09806cc0dc7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

#### EDIT:

I realised I never really gave you an alternative. Here's what I would probably do:

```
pub enum SearchOptions {
    CaseSensitive,
    CaseInsensitive
}

pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str, options: SearchOptions) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        let check = match options {
            SearchOptions::CaseSensitive => line.contains(query),   
            SearchOptions::CaseInsensitive => line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()),   
        };
    
        if check {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }

    results
}
```

This is about as far as you could get "de-dupe"'ing it.

#### Original answer:

The actual problem is that you're trying to pass the `contents` around when its bound to the lifetime `'a` ... but what you really want to be "case insensitive" is the `query`.

This isn't bound to the lifetime `'a` in quite the same way and as such ... works:

```
pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase();
    search(&query, contents)
}
```

[Here it is on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=03f77a892b765a921500e78b2fb58967&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

You'll need to still duplicate the logic though ... because you need to match the lowercase query with the lowercase line ... which is demonstrated in the examples in the book:

```
if line.to_lowercase().contains(&query) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ each LINE is converted to lowercase here in the insensitive search
    results.push(line);
}
```

"How do I stop duplicating the logic?" - well they're not quite the same in the first place. I think your attempt wasn't quite what you were after in the first place (happy to be corrected though).

Comment: Lower-casing the query yields a very different answer though; I don't see how it solves the OP issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I checked the book examples - the book actually lowercases the query so the OP is headed in the wrong direction anyway. They've introduced a bug which isn't present in the book because they've done something completely different. Instead of helping with the error I've attempted to point them in the right direction given what they're doing isn't an issue if following the examples correctly. Either way though, I think the "logic de-duplication" isn't an achievable goal given the two core lines of the logic are required to be different. This is what I'm trying to point out at the end.

Comment: I've added an example of what I might do in this situation... but it strays away from the examples you're following in the book. I based the top half of my answer on what you're doing in wrong whilst following the book.

Comment: I understand that the behavior of the the function would differ from the book in that the returned strings would all be lowercase. I'm not really interested in rewriting grep or duplicating the functionality in the book exactly. But I have often written code where one of two functions with identical signatures calls the other after a short prelude and I thought others might have similar issues with functions returning string references. The answer I hoped to get is something along the lines of, 'change the return values of both functions to Vec<String>' or something better that I can't imagine

Comment: @Kaan I was just trying to keep it as close to the source material as possible. Even though I think my solution is acceptable in honesty I would've just used `String` instances everywhere here and refactored it into references where appropriate later on. Rust programmers generally try to avoid allocations where possible so you'll see references used a lot - but I personally would've reached directly for `String` instances and refactored later. I hope my solution helps you anyway.

Comment: @Kaan I have updated my answer to use `String` instances. Obviously this will allocate more than the original answer but at least its another alternative for you.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm accepting your answer. I think probably the correct way to do this is to duplicate part of the functionality and continue returning &str vectors as in the book and your original answer. Since you've added the string return type as well, unless someone else comes up with something genius I think this is as good as it's going to get. I was kind of hoping someone would be able to tell me how to do it with the call to search like I wanted while still returning <&str> but maybe that's just wanting to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @Kaan My original edit does still use string references... it however introduces a `SearchOptions` enum and duplicates 1 of the lines (the `contains` call is duplicated). I think that's as close as you'll get to what you want using references. Glad I could help ayway.

Answer (score 1):

You have introduced an impossible constraint on the lifetime of variable `contents2`; by writing `&'a` you are attempting to assign to it the same lifetime as to the `contents` argument, but it is created and destroyed within the scope of `search_case_insensitive` and thus is outlived by `contents`.

In order for `contents2` to outlive the body of `search_case_insensitive` you would need to either return it as a `String` and assign to some variable outside of it or pass it to `search_case_insensitive` by reference as long as it already exists as a `String` elsewhere.

Citing [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.0/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html):

> It's important to understand that **lifetime annotations are
>   descriptive, not prescriptive**. This means that how long a reference is
>   valid is determined by the code, not by the annotations.